# How to append DataFrame into multiple tabs of Excel files which are on Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, append, filepath, pandas.excelwriter

As addressed in the title, for this question currently I am try using this way to do it:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path,
                mode='a',
                engine="openpyxl",
                if_sheet_exists="overlay",
                ) as writer:
example_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', header=False,
                           index=False, startrow=8, startcol=2)
```

just here the target Excel file is on Google Drive. I can't figure out what should I set to the varible file_path, so that the example_dataframe can be appended to the target Excel file's sheet 'sheet1'. In other words, how can I let the function find the Excel file on Google Drive?

(The authentification process of connecting Google Drive has all been set up.)

Many thanks in advance!

Best,
Xubo

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand the detail of your situation from `The authentification process of connecting Google Drive has all been set up.`, if you want to edit the XLSX file on Google Drive, I think that it is required to download it and edit it, and then, upload it as the update. If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: Hey Tanaike,

Thanks a lot for the reply! By that sentence I mean that I have used package pydrive2 to successfully manage to access Google drive.
I think the key of the question is exactly that, if it is possible that I can edit Excel files directly via Google drive without downloading it, and here the edit means ‘append’ something to existing Excel file, instead of ‘create’ a totally new file or ‘update’ fully for a file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `if it is possible that I can edit Excel files directly via Google drive without downloading it`, I thoguht that this cannot be achieved when Drive API is used. So, I proposed the above flow. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: No apology at all! I will also try the way you proposed, thank you very much for answering!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When Drive API is used, the XLSX data is required to be downloaded. But, in your situation, I think that you might be able to do the flow you want to achieve without creating the file from the downloaded data.